# How can I look for duplicate files from different base folders in bash?

Tags: bash, duplicate, deduplication, fdupes

I know `fdupes`, which can find duplicate files from various directories I provide it:

```
fdupes -r <directoryA> <directoryB> <...>
```

But this seems to “throw all files into the same basket”, so if I provide two directories, `/aaa` and `/bbb` for example, it finds not only files that identically exist in `/aaa` *and* `/bbb`, but also duplicates *within* `/aaa`, and duplicates *within* `/bbb`.

Is there any way to look for duplicates *between* two directories, *but not in the same base directory*?

My very usual use case is that `aaa` contains a handful of files and `bbb` thousands and thousands of files, and I want to be able to throw away `aaa` if I have all files from it elsewhere. So, searching for duplicates *within `bbb`* is a complete waste of energy/time.

Comment: (1) `jdupes` (and maybe `fdupes`) can generate a list that is (under some assumptions) parsable. (2) What if a file is duplicated twice in `aaa` and three times in `bbb`? Do you want to see all the five pathnames?

Comment: you may have different way to do so depending on the filesystem. Btrfs has some tools to help, as well as zfs. regarding ext* family you may use md5sum or sha256sum and compare hash to find duplicate.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, if a file is duplicated twice in `aaa` and three times in `bbb`, I want to see it 6 times: `aaa/a1 <-> bbb/b1`, `aaa/a1 <-> bbb/b2`, `aaa/a1 <-> bbb/b3`; `aaa/a2 <-> bbb/b1`, `aaa/a2 <-> bbb/b2`, `aaa/a2 <-> bbb/b3`. I do not want to see `aaa/a1 <-> aaa/a2`, nor `bbb/b1 <-> bbb/b2` nor `bbb/b2 <-> bbb/b3` nor `bbb/b1 <-> bbb/B3`.

Comment: My very usual use case is that `aaa` contains a handful of files and `bbb` thousands and thousands of files, and I want to be able to throw away `aaa` if I have all files from it elsewhere. So, searching for duplicates *within `bbb`* is a complete waste of energy/time.

Comment: Well, tools I have used list duplicates in sets, hence 5 in my example (2+3=5). It seems you want to see ordered pairs (2x3=6). Your last comment explains a lot. "A handful" and "thousands and thousands" make the situation quite specific. If you want to optimize for this scenario then place your last comment in the question.

Comment: Try `jdupes -Ir /aaa /bbb`. In the "2+3" scenario it will give you two distinct pairs and you wont know if files across pairs are different. It won't show you the 5th file.

Comment: "I want to be able to throw away `aaa` if I have all files from it elsewhere." -- Is "all" important? You don't want to remove files one by one, right? You want to remove all or nothing of `aaa`. If so, then even your "see it 6 times" requires further parsing, to make sure *each* file from `aaa` exists somewhere in `bbb`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I will try `jdupes`. Just to answer your question: Since there only are a handful of files in `aaa`, handling them one by one is no problem. And whenever there are a few files left after the handling, that's fine as well: I then know that I have to find a logical storage place for them (or just delete those which are not needed).